# Guava Optional working with multiple objects and fields

Tags: java, guava

I have few classes:

```
    public class Person {
        private String personName;
        private String personSurname;
        private int age;
        private Task task;
        private Document document;
    //getters and setters

    public class Task {
        private long taskNumber;
        private String taskDescription;
        private String taskPriority;
    //get&set

    public class Document {
        private String docName;
        private String docDescription;
        private long docNumber;
        private String docType;
        private DocumentAuthor documentAuthor;
    // get&set

    public class DocumentAuthor {
        private String documentAuthorName;
        private long documentAuthorNumber;
        private String documentAuthorDescription;
    // get&set
```

And after create Person object I need to build description (with StringBuilder) from some fields like: personName, personSurname, taskDescription, docDescription and documentAuthorDescription. The thing is when I must check nullables of some objects/fields (I don’t want to store nulls in description). In this moment I do this on this way:

```
    private static String setStringBuilder(Person person) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            //create Optional objects for every class except Person:
            Optional<Document> personDocument = Optional.fromNullable(person.getDocument());
            Optional<Task> personTask = Optional.fromNullable(person.getTask());
            Optional<DocumentAuthor> personDocumentAuthor = Optional.fromNullable(person.getDocument().getDocumentAuthor());
            //create List where i add fields for description
            List<Optional<String>> list = new ArrayList();
            list.add(Optional.fromNullable(person.getPersonName()));
            list.add(Optional.fromNullable(person.getPersonSurname()));
            //in this section i check presents of objects:
            if (personDocument.isPresent()) {
                list.add(Optional.fromNullable(person.getDocument().getDocDescription()));
                list.add(Optional.fromNullable(person.getDocument().getDocType()));
            }
            if (personTask.isPresent()) {
                list.add(Optional.fromNullable(person.getTask().getTaskDescription()));
            }
            if (personDocumentAuthor.isPresent()) {
                list.add(Optional.fromNullable(person.getDocument().getDocumentAuthor().getDocumentAuthorName()));
            }
            //here i build StringBuilder from fields stored in list
            for (Optional<String> optional : list) {
                if (optional.isPresent()) {
                    sb.append(optional.get());
                    sb.append(" ");
                }
            }
            String description = sb.toString();
            return description;
        }
```

But I believe there is some coolest way to do this with Guava Optionals. Especially when I check for nulls witch if’s. So pls give me some advices and forgive me my bad bad english :)

Comment: None of this is really going to be any cleaner than with nulls.

Comment: So i can't do any better with Optionals?

Comment: Not for this task, no.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the "coolest" way to solve a problem, focus instead on the "cleanest", "safest", and "easiest to maintain" solutions.

Dealing with `null` is certainly error-prone, and has caused [countless bugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer#History), but they are a part of the Java language, and sometimes they're what you need.

In particular, it generally makes more sense to expose `Optional`s at API boundaries (e.g. as the return type of public methods), rather than return possibly-null values. That allows your callers to confidently and safely work with your code without fear of unexpected NPEs. Your private implementation may well be better off just using `null` or some other concept to represent absence however.

As a rule of thumb, `Optional` should make your code safer and easier to use. If you find yourself jumping through hoops in order to make things `Optional` step back and consider alternative approaches.